# VS2017 Deploy to ARM

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I can usually find resolutions to my problems here, but no one seems to have experienced the problem I'm having.

I'm using VS2017, building a UWP app for Win10 Anniversary edition. The app deploys fine to the Local Machine and the emulator. However, when I try to start debugging on the phone (MS Lumia 950), the Deploy process finishes successfully almost instantly. Then I get the "Project needs to be deployed before it can be started..." message. I'm not seeing any error messages during deployment, just the one after deployment apparently succeeds. If I try to deploy from the Build menu, I get the same rapid deployment.

The phone and PC both are updated with the Creators update. I have rebooted the pc and the phone. I have checked the 'Deploy' option in Config Manager. The phone is unlocked when I deploy. If I unplug the USB cable, I get the expected "Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found." message. I don't have another USB-C cable to try, but I can see and explore the phone from File Explorer in Win10. I used "WinAppDeployCmd List -ip 127.0.0.1" to make sure the app really isn't on the phone.

I've developed some other UWP apps in VS2015, this is my first go with 2017. Sorry if I was overly verbose, I want to provide as much detail as I can. I don't know what to try next.

Thanks for any insight.
Don

Comment: Are you sure the app supports the version of os on the lumia 950?

Comment: How about a blank UWP app?

Comment: I wound up removing and reinstalling VS2017 because I was encountering a number of strange problems. Now my app is deploying as I expect it to.